# Stereographic projections - equation of a plane question

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vectors

The [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xDbw.jpg) I'm trying to understand.  I don't get why $k$ is unique.

When trying to find the equation of a plane, suppose we're given a normal vector $n=(x_o,y_o,z_o)$ and a point on the plane $p^*=(x^*,y^*,z^*)$.  Then the set of all points on the plane are those points $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $((x,y,z)-(x^*,y^*,z^*))\cdot(x_o,y_o,z_o)=0$.

Using dot product rules, $(x,y,z)\cdot(x_o,y_o,z_o)=(x^*,y^*,z^*)\cdot(x_o,y_o,z_o)$.

But $p^*=(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ can be any point on the plane, and using two different points would change the right hand side of the equation (i.e. two different $k$ values for the same plane).

Help?

Comment: If u change the base point to q, RHS of the last eq. doesnt change since (q-p)*n is 0.

Answer (score 1):

No, using two different points in the plane will *not* change the right hand side, for both points will satisfy the equation of the plane. Think about it.

To be more precise, adopting your notation then if $(x',y',z')$ is another point in the plane and you consider using it instead of $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ then by the equation of the plane, $(x',y',z')\cdot(x_o,y_o,z_o)=(x^*,y^*,z^*)\cdot(x_o,y_o,z_o)$. The left hand side of this equation is the right hand side of your “new” equation.